# Editing a list of several fields

Tags: custom-post-types, lists

I need to edit a list of quotes. Every quote consists of a (short) text, author's name, author's title.

What is the best way to create an editor of such data in WordPress?

It seems that the simplest solution is to create a custom post type. Should the quote text become the title of a post? (It is not quite the title, logically.)

If not with post types, then how?

Note, that I need two lists of quotes (in two languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a custom post type. Use the editor to hold the quote in the site's default language and create a new box to hold the translated version. A second meta box can hold the author's name and title. For the post title, just use something descriptive, so that you can find the post later on for editing. When you get to the template, just don't use `the_title()`.